# ASP.Net MVC how to save more than one row to data Base

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, timetable

I would to ask you about my project time table
I am currently learning this technique
so please help me

This image for choose a group:
[image]

I want in this table for each field added to the database and then displayed in the label:
[image]

this is my controller

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TimeTable2.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace TimeTable2.Controllers
{
    public class TablesController : Controller
    {
        private table_systemEntities1 db = new table_systemEntities1();


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]


        public ActionResult TheTables()
        {
            PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList();
            PopulateClassroomsDropDownList();
            PopulateCoursesDropDownList();
            PopulateTeachersDropDownList();
            PopulateFacultiesDropDownList();
            PopulateLevelsDropDownList();

            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

        public JsonResult TheTables([Bind(Include = "TabelsID,TeacherID,CourseID,LevelID,DepartmentID,ClassRoomID,TimesID,DaysID,Years,Semester,Measure")] Tabels tabels)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Tabels.Add(tabels);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (DataException /* dex */)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again .");
            }
            ViewBag.ClassRoomID = new SelectList(db.Class_Room, "ClassRoomID", "Name", tabels.ClassRoomID);
            ViewBag.DaysID = new SelectList(db.Days, "DayID", "Name", tabels.DaysID);
            ViewBag.LevelID = new SelectList(db.Level, "LevelID", "Name", tabels.LevelID);
            ViewBag.TeacherID = new SelectList(db.Teacher, "TeacherID", "Name", tabels.TeacherID);
            ViewBag.TimesID = new SelectList(db.Times, "TimesID", "Name", tabels.DaysID);
            ViewBag.CourseID = new SelectList(db.Course, "CourseID", "Name", tabels.CourseID);
            ViewBag.FacultyID = new SelectList(db.Faculty, "FacultyID", "Name", tabels.FacultyID);
            ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(db.Department, "DepartmentID", "Name", tabels.DepartmentID);
            ViewBag.LevelID = new SelectList(db.Level, "LevelID", "Name", tabels.LevelID);


            return Json(tabels, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }

        public ActionResult DetailsofTable()
        {

            PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList();
            PopulateClassroomsDropDownList();
            PopulateCoursesDropDownList();
            PopulateTeachersDropDownList();
            PopulateFacultiesDropDownList();
            PopulateLevelsDropDownList();


            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult CreateTheTable()
        {

            PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList();
            PopulateClassroomsDropDownList();
            PopulateCoursesDropDownList();
            PopulateTeachersDropDownList();
            PopulateFacultiesDropDownList();
            PopulateLevelsDropDownList();

            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult GetDepartmentById(int ID)
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return Json(db.Department.Where(p => p.FacultyID == ID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        public JsonResult GetTeacherById(int ID)
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return Json(db.Teacher_Course.Where(p => p.CourseID == ID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        public JsonResult GetFacultyById(int ID)
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return Json(db.Class_Room.Where(p => p.ClassRoomID == ID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        public JsonResult GetCoursesById(int ID)
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return Json(db.Teacher_Course.Where(p => p.DepartmentID == ID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        private void PopulateDepartmentsDropDownList(object selectedDepartment = null)
        {
            var departmentsQuery = from d in db.Department
                                   orderby d.Name
                                   select d;
            ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(departmentsQuery, "DepartmentID", "Name", selectedDepartment);
        }
        private void PopulateClassroomsDropDownList(object selectedClassRooms = null)
        {
            var classroomsQuery = from d in db.Class_Room
                                   orderby d.Name
                                   select d;
            ViewBag.ClassRoomID = new SelectList(classroomsQuery, "ClassRoomID", "Name", selectedClassRooms);
        }
        private void PopulateCoursesDropDownList(object selectedCourses = null)
        {
            var coursesQuery = from d in db.Course
                                  orderby d.Name
                                  select d;
            ViewBag.CourseID = new SelectList(coursesQuery, "CourseID", "Name", selectedCourses);
        }
        private void PopulateTeachersDropDownList(object selectedTeachers = null)
        {
            var teacherQuery = from d in db.Teacher
                                  orderby d.Name
                                  select d;
            ViewBag.TeacherID = new SelectList(teacherQuery, "TeacherID", "Name", selectedTeachers);
        }
        private void PopulateFacultiesDropDownList(object selectedFaculties = null)
        {
            var facultyQuery = from d in db.Faculty
                               orderby d.Name
                               select d;
            ViewBag.FacultyID = new SelectList(facultyQuery, "FacultyID", "Name", selectedFaculties);
        }
        private void PopulateLevelsDropDownList(object selectedLevels = null)
        {
            var levelQuery = from d in db.Level
                               orderby d.Name
                               select d;
            ViewBag.LevelID = new SelectList(levelQuery, "LevelID", "Name", selectedLevels);
        }
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

so how can I save more than one field in the database in the same time

Sorry I can not speak English

Answer (score 0):

To insert multiple rows in Entity Framework, you can use **AddRange**.

```
db.Tabels.AddRange(tabels);
```

Please check [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.addrange(v=vs.113).aspx)

Hope it Helps!!